# How to convert mapply to pmap or similar so data can be grouped in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a mapply function that runs a sum expression so that each row the sum starts from the same number. ie row 1: sum starting from row 1, row 2: sum starting from row 2 etc. This works fine, however I now need to be able to run it on grouped data and I'm having some trouble getting this to run. I believe `pmap` is the analogue of `mapply` within `dplyr` so I'm trying to use this with grouped data.

The data looks something like:

```
df <- tibble(NCP = c(96.05655668, 16.94332276, 19.8844913, 17.74200903, 17.6135507, 
                     15.1, 12.2,  13.1, 3.3, 47.8, 12.3,1.8),
             time_bin =  c(100,200,300,400,500, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700),
             site = site <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
             output = c(14.01221047, 6.51265852, 5.399067538, 3.743397662, 2.02022025, 
                         123.1815734, 106.8239387, 92.50710604, 75.85374217, 71.30922055,
                        23.02892565, 3.151210501))
```

Where output is the intended result.

The original code runs fine on one site and is the following:

```
df <- df %>% filter(site == "A")

len <- nrow(df)
       df$out <- mapply(
         function(i, tb, tblag) sum(df$NCP[i:len]/tb - df$NCP[i:len]/tblag),
         seq_len(len), exp(-0.0008 * df$time_bin), exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin[-len])))
```

To create the equivalent for grouped data I've tried running the following:

```
 df1 <- df%>%
  group_by(site) %>% 
  summarise(nrow = n())

df <- right_join(df1, df)

df <- df %>% group_by(site) %>% 
mutate(out = pmap(.,  function(i, tb, tblag){sum(df$NCP[i:max(nrow)]/tb - df$NCP[i:max(nrow)]/tblag),
                  seq_len(max(nrow)), exp(-0.0008 * df$time_bin), exp(-0.0008 * c(0, df$time_bin[-max(nrow)])))}
```

Where I have used `summarise` to create the length of the row and joined the data tables together, then used `max(nrow)` to grab the length for each group. I feel like this should work, if not particularly elegant, however I can't get the code to run. I've tried playing around with syntax a bit, but I cant get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just translating your attempt using `pmap_dbl` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df%>%
  group_by(site) %>% 
  mutate(output = pmap_dbl(list(seq_len(n()), exp(-0.0008 * time_bin), 
                                exp(-0.0008 * c(0, time_bin[-n()]))), 
                  function(i, tb, tblag) sum(NCP[i:n()]/tb - NCP[i:n()]/tblag)))
```